# store the variable for the call inside the select sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to store the variable for the call inside the select
example:

```
DECLARE @Qty INT, @workdays INT, @dailygoal INT, @bufferstock INT;
SELECT 
    @Qty = SUM(qty) [qty],
    @workdays = 25 [workdays],
    @dailygoal = (SUM(qty) / 25) [dailygoal],
    @bufferstock = (@dailygoal * MAX(leadtime)) [bufferstock]
FROM table
```

Comment: Please do not add random tags to your question.

Comment: And how will you use these variables?

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking here. Are you saying that in your last expression, `(@dailygoal * MAX(leadtime)) [bufferstock]` you want `@dailygoal`  to represent `(SUM(qty) / 25)`? Also why are you aliasing your columns when you are assigning the values to a variable? The alias will cause a syntax error.

Comment: @Chetan use it for calculations according to previously entered variables

Comment: @Larnu yeah right like that, to minimize like this
((SUM(stock.stock)+MAX([fs].[git]))-(((SUM(qty)/25)*25)+((SUM(qty)/25)*MAX(branch.time ))))+MAX([fs].[adjustment])
) / NULLIF(MAX([dk].[koli]), 0)

Answer (score 1):

**Remove Alias Name ..**

```
    DECLARE @Qty INT, @workdays INT, @dailygoal INT, @bufferstock INT;
SELECT 
    @Qty = SUM(Bonus_amount),
    @workdays = 25,
    @dailygoal = (SUM(Bonus_amount) / 25),
    @bufferstock = (@dailygoal * 5) 
FROM [dbo].[Bonus]
select @Qty,@workdays,@dailygoal,@bufferstock
```

Comment: it only shows the last row, how to display all of them

Comment: Not getting your point.
i am displaying all declared variables.

Answer (score 1):

The query you have will error, due to your aliases. When you *assign* a variable in a `SELECT` you do not alias the column.

Also, although you can do syntax like you have, where you reference a variable assigned elsewhere in the statement, I would err against it; though not documented I would not be surprised if has the same antipattern as documented in [Antipattern use of recursive variable assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) and that the latter variable *could* be derived prior to the former. This would mean that the variable `@bufferstock` could be assigned the value `NULL`, as the value of `@dailygoal` was `NULL` when the expressed was determined.

Instead, just repeat the expression:

```sql
DECLARE @V1 int,
        @V2 int;

SELECT @V1 = SUM(V.I),
       @V2 = SUM(V.I) * MAX(V.I)
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3))V(I);

SELECT @V1,
       @V2;
```

If you don't want to do that, then use a derived table (a CTE or Subquery) to define the expression instead. I use a CTE here:

```sql
DECLARE @V1 int,
        @V2 int;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SUM(V.I) AS S,
           MAX(V.I) AS M
    FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3))V(I))
SELECT @V1 = S,
       @V2 = S*M
FROM CTE;

SELECT @V1,
       @V2;
```

Using a derived table for your query would mean something like the following:

```sql
DECLARE @Qty int,
        @workdays int,
        @dailygoal int,
        @bufferstock int;

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT SUM(qty) AS qty,
           SUM(qty) / 25 AS dailygoal,
           MAX(leadtime) AS leadtime
    FROM dbo.[table])
SELECT @Qty = qty,
       @workdays = 25,
       @dailygoal = dailygoal,
       @bufferstock = dailygoal * leadtime
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: In this *particular* instance, there is scalar aggregation, so you are *guaranteed* to get one row. It's only undefined behaviour when there are multiple rows. The value of the variable on the righ hand side will be the value it was before assignment, in this case `NULL`

Comment: @Charlieface that's what I thought would happen, but it didn't in practice. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2583d1316128c5913853b6893334dd04)

Comment: Hmm interesting. I found a note [on microsoft.com about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#code-try-6) *"**Warning** If there are multiple assignment clauses in a single SELECT statement, SQL Server does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the expressions. Note that effects are only visible if there are references among the assignments."* One more reason not to muck around with variables like that. The funniest thing is that even on one row the order of the `SELECT` **expression list** is undefined

Comment: There's the documentation I wanted! Thanks, @Charlieface . :) Yes, I "knew" it was an antipattern (like the linked documentation0 but I couldn't specifically find the reference, which is why I erred against said logic.